# How to access text value from textfield using objective c with tag?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistackview

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCuPI.png)Actually i am new to objective c. My problem is how to fetch text from textfield with tag. Where textfields are located inside nested uistackview. So i am not able to get the value of text field from that nested uistackview. How it should be fetched text from stackview using objective c?

As i shown in image i am getting text from only last textfield not from above two. I am dynamically created textfields, how should i get each text field text?

```
else if ([key isEqualToString: textbox]){

            NSDictionary *widthAndHieght = [rowNames objectForKey:key];

            //NSLog(@"Hieght: %@",[widthAndHieght objectForKey:@"height"]);
            //NSLog(@"Width: %@",[widthAndHieght objectForKey:@"width"]);

            int height = [[widthAndHieght objectForKey:@"height"]intValue];
            int width = [[widthAndHieght objectForKey:@"width"]intValue];
            NSString *intTag = [[widthAndHieght objectForKey:@"tag"] objectForKey:@"tagInt"];

            myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
            myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
            myTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
            //NSString *textFieldTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tagValue];
            //NSString *textFieldTag = myTextField.text;
            NSInteger b = [intTag integerValue];
            myTextField.tag = b;
            NSLog(@" Textfield tag:%ld",(long)myTextField.tag);
            myTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            myTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            myTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
            //[layout addSubview:myTextField];
            [layout addArrangedSubview:myTextField];


            NSNumber *tagNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:b];
            [arrayOfTagValue addObject:tagNumber];
            NSLog(@" tag values :%@",arrayOfTagValue);

            NSDictionary *bindings3 = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(layout, myTextField);

            // Set the constraints for the label to be pinned equally with padding
            [greyView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(30)-[myTextField]-(30)-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:bindings3]];
            [greyView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(30)-[myTextField]-(30)-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:bindings3]];
        }
```

Below is the code where i need to get each text value but not able to achieve. How it will be done?

```
-(void) sendBridge:(UITextField *)textField{

    for(int i = 0; i< [arrayOfTagValue count]; i++){

        NSLog(@"Value :%@",[arrayOfTagValue objectAtIndex:i]);

        if(textField == myTextField) {

            myTextField.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            NSLog(@" text :%@",myTextField.text);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this :-

```
UITextField *txt = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:0]; 
NSString *strValue = txt.text;
```

Comment: But i am not using self.view im using stack view.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example:

in your viewcontroller.h

```
@interface UIViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate> {

 UITextField * listTitle;

}
```

in your viewController.m:

```
listTitle = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:10];
        listTitle.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        listTitle.delegate = self;
        listTitle.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        listTitle.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Bold" size:14];
        listTitle.textColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:45/255.0f green:45/255.0f blue:54/255.0f alpha:1];
        listTitle.text=@"";


NOW you can use delegate methods:

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if(textField == listTitle) { //or textField.tag == 10
       //here you know the user is using your textfield listTitle 

    }
}

-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if(textField == listTitle) {
       //here you know the user is using your textfield listTitle 
       listTitle.textcolor = [UIColor redColor];
       listTitle.text = @"Hello";
    }

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Nope its not working. As per i am looking to get values from nested stackview.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using tags, you could add your TextFields in a

IBOutletCollection and refer to them like that. In that way, you could loop through your IBOutletCollection Array containing the TextFields and get the values.

This is a lot safer than tags, as it less prone to user error.

EXAMPLE:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UITextField) NSArray *TextFieldsCollection;


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    for (UITextField *textField in self.TextFieldsCollection) {
        NSLog(@"Placeholder: %@", textField.placeholder);
        NSLog(@"Text: %@", textField.text);
    }
}

@end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using UIStackview you can do:

```
 for (UITextField *txtField in [stackview subviews]) {

            if (txtField.tag == 1) {
                //...
            } else {
                //...
            }   
 }
```

> Anyway nice answer George!!